# Why can I not use my picam v2?

Tags: raspicam, picamera

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -o test.jpg gives me the error below. I am trying to set up the camera with octoprint.

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera gives me
supported=1 detected=1

/boot/cmdline.txt:

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=67035adc-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repa
```

/boot/config.txt:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size min$
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2
#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
```

New error: raspistill -o test.jpg
Camera control callback  cmd=0x4f525245mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board

Comment: did you do what the error message suggests?

Comment: I did sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get update with no luck.

Comment: I see that a lot of people are saying that it might be because another program is trying to use the cam, but I do not know how to see if there is or how to stop said program.

Comment: please add contents of your `/boot/cmdline.txt` and `/boot/config.txt` to your question ... or, yo may need `GPU_MEM=144` (or higher) in `config.txt` - if my 30 seconds of googling that error message is accurate

Comment: Thanks I have updated it with the info from those files.

Comment: please format it so it's readable

Comment: How do I do that? I am very new to all of this.

Comment: done for you ... the `{}` button indents code/output so it's nicely readable

Comment: try adding `GPU_MEM=144` to `config.txt`

Comment: I have updated the post with the new error I am getting. Makes me think the camera is busted...

Comment: Which pi is it? Because, oddly enough, my pi3A+ running octoprint suddenly can't even detect the camera - and - my other pi3A+ can't either - it's all a bit weird (haven't used it in a few months)